# How can I get Shell history in IPython console

Tags: shell, ipython, history

I want to parse Shell history commands in IPython console, however, `!history` doesn't give me Shell history commands in IPython. How can I get the list of Shell history in IPython?

Comment: What shell are you using?

Comment: `bash` keeps its history in `./bash_history` (at least in a default linux installation).  Found this with a we search for 'bash history'.

Comment: try this:
```!cat ~/.bash_history```

Comment: I'm using Bash shell in Ubuntu in Docker. Unfortunately, `$HOME/.bash_history` does not exists even if `$HISTFILE` points to it. However, the command `history` still works.